# Why does Silverlight PollingDuplex service timeout when running on IIS5.1?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, iis, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I have a Silverlight client, with a PollingDuplex service client, which works fine under IIS7 - callback messages are received clientside without any problems. However, the same client and service fails on IIS5.1, with the server error `The IOutputChannel timed out`. It's clear that on 5.1, the server can't call the client back - but why?

Both tests in IIS7 and IIS5.1 are run entirely on the local machine (ie. both client and server are local) - there are no firewalls getting in the way.

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427814/wcf-silverlight-call-back-to-server-fails-in-iis) of any use to you?

Comment: Gert - no, sorry. I probably wasn't clear enough - my service actually works in IIS5.1 - I can call it OK, it's just the callback bit that fails - ie. Server -> Client notification... thanks though